# Advantages and disadvantages of using delete from vs. copying the data and using drop

Tags: mysql, select, delete-row, mysql-5.5, drop-table

The MySQL queries

```
 delete from t where not condition;
```

and

```
 create table s select * from t where condition;
 drop table t;
```

are very similar. (Here, `condition` in the one query is the same as `condition` in the other.)
One advantage of the second method is that it allows you inspect `s` before dropping `t`, to make sure nothing went wrong with your query. That's a very important consideration, and I don't wish to minimize it, but I'm wondering what *other* pros and cons exist for either of above queries vis-à-vis the other.

Comment: The two are not equivalent. The second drops the entire `t` table.

Comment: @MattBall, right, but you have `s` which has the same rows as `t` does (at the end of the day) in the first query. Let me make a clarifying edit....

Answer (score 1):

As for the second query, whenever you create a temporary table in any database, it defragments tablespaces and degrades database performance. I strongly recommend not to follow the second approach.

If you really want to be absolutely sure of what you are doing, you can use something like the following code:

```
/*
DELETE
-- */ SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE condition;
```

When you are sure that the rows returned are exactly the ones you want to delete, you can easily comment the comment start of the first line, like:

```
-- /*
DELETE
-- */ SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE condition;
```

I use the same approach before I run any `DELETE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is far better, that is why there exists a delete' command in SQL. There is **no need to reinvent the delete command**:

1- There is **no need to change your schema** (create s, drop t) when you want to delete some rows.

2- t may have **relationships with other tables** that you may want to preserve. You may even want to cascade the delete to remove some other dependent rows in some other tables, use triggers on delete and...

3- As for the advantage of checking the rows before deleting that you mentioned, well you could do the select before using the delete command too.

4- Your tables might have **links to some other app logic**, let's say ORM classes, SPs for reporting and.. Do you want to create a new class in your code or update your existing SPs every time you want to remove a couple of rows?